# Heat equation and its gradient flow

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let $u$ be the solution of the heat equation in $\Omega\subset \mathbb R$. So $u(x, t)$ is the solution of 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u(x, t), \qquad x\in \Omega, t\geq 0,\qquad (1)$$
with the boundary condition $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(x, t)=0, x\in\partial \Omega$.
The associated energy is given by 
$$E(u)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega}\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(x,t)\Big)^2dx$$
in the sense that (1) can be rewritten as 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x,t)=-\frac{d}{du}E(u)$$.
My question is how can I obtain that
$$\frac{d}{du}E(u)=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u(x, t)?$$